# de-dupe my mysql database - similar rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have a DB table containing a list of companies:

```
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| company | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| id      | int(200)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| image   | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Which contains a list of around 15,000 companies.
I want to de-dupe similar rows, as the table data has come from multiple sources.

For example, if I search companies for 'lloyds', I get results for 'lloyds, lloyds plc'. I want to combine any companies that just have 'ltd, plc, group' etc. on the end, and remove the dupes.

However, I also need to keep the 'image' column data if it exists from either match result. so for example from this result I want to de dupe to simply 'lloyds' from row 1 but keep the 'image' from row 2:

```
select * from companies where match(company) against ('*lloyds*')

*************************** 1. row ***************************
company: Lloyds
     id: 9034
  image:
*************************** 2. row ***************************
company: Lloyds plc
     id: 3202
  image:LOGO_URL
```

Lastly, I also have a DB table of jobs, each with a corresponding company ID.
I need to keep a record/array of all removed company ID's, and what they have been updated to from the de-dupe so I can update the company ID in my jobs DB, otherwise I will have jobs with a non existent company.

How can I achieve this? What queries will I need?

Comment: This is not a fun task. Can you provide representative CREATE and INSERT statements for BOTH tables.

Comment: but "Lloyds" is not the same as "Lloyds plc" . how do you want to handle this

Comment: @BerndBuffen agreed they are not technically the same, but at the moment I provide jobs by the best match so someone searching jobs from 'lloyds' will not see jobs from 'lloyds plc'. So I want to de-dupe to simply 'lloyds', as using the fulltext search if someone actually searches 'lloyds plc', they will still get all jobs under 'lloyds' including the lloyds plc specific ones

Comment: Please check this select if it found the right row. if it works i finished the query: SELECT d1.*,d2.*
FROM dedup d1
LEFT JOIN dedup d2 ON d1.name LIKE CONCAT(d2.name,'%') AND d1.id <> d2.id
WHERE d2.name IS NOT NULL;

Comment: @BerndBuffen it selects the correct row (among others), but also has a bunch of false matches:

SELECT d1.*,d2.* FROM companies d1 LEFT JOIN companies d2 ON d1.company LIKE CONCAT(d2.company,'%') AND d1.id <> d2.id WHERE d2.company IS NOT NULL

it matches 'AA' with 'Aalpha solutions'. Can the query be modified so the wildcard is more a regex list of acceptable wildcards? e.g 'ltd | plc | uk | recruitment'